# select box options selenium web driver & java

Tags: drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I am newbie to selenium. I was trying to select a value from the select box in `telugumatrimony.com`, using `firefox 12.0 and eclipse` ...

In this site, for religion select box, when i try to select " Hindu" by using this sentence

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='RELIGION']")).sendKeys("Hindu");
```

it is selecting a different option .

Also, i selected RELIGION and Mother Tongue using these statements (these two work fine using these statements)

```
WebDriver  wd=new FirefoxDriver();
wd.get("http:telugumatrimony.com");

wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='REGISTERED_BY']")).sendKeys("Myself");

Select dropdow=new Select(wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='REGISTERED_BY']")));
dropdow.selectByVisibleText("Son");

Select dropdown = new Select(wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='RELIGION']")));
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);

Select dropdown1=new Select(wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='MOTHERTONGUE']")));
dropdown1.selectByIndex(49);
```

After this , the caste comes...

```
Select dropdown2=new Select(wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='TEMP_CASTE_NORMAL']")));
dropdown2.selectByIndex(1);
```

This is giving some error.

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"

What is wrong ???? (OR) what is the xpath to be written to select CASTE ??????

Thanks,
Sudha

Comment: Check the HTML once more...clearly...though CASTE is displayed as dropdown, it's entries are not registered as Options...they are listed in ul&li format..somewhere else..

Comment: @Anuragh27crony  Thanku, i checked the source code,after u told ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element
>   should have been "select" but was "input"

comes because your trying to pass other HTML element other than `select` element, in this line:

```
Select dropdown2=new Select(wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='TEMP_CASTE_NORMAL']")));
```

Look at the doc constructor of `Select` [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html#Select%28org.openqa.selenium.WebElement%29). It clearly says:

> Constructor. A check is made that the given element is, indeed, a
>   SELECT tag. If it is not, then an UnexpectedTagNameException is
>   thrown.

which is the root cause for your problem.

Comment: The above works if i write ..                                                                      Thread.sleep(3000);                                                             
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='TEMP_CASTE_NORMAL']")).sendKeys("Balija");